# how to Resolve this error it comes im my web page when i run it

Tags: c#

Error:

> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.

Code:

```
 private object Session(string p)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: just comment the raw and return null, if you don't need implementation.

Comment: Maybe just... implement the method body:D?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: You're throwing an exception and you're asking why is that exception being thrown? Please consider learning any programming/.NET basics before actually asking a question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems to lack even a minimal understanding of the topic at hand.

Answer (score 1):

By simply implementing this method. You are explicitly raising the `NotImplementedException` exception that's why you are getting error.

Instead of raising exception put your implementation code inside the function or if you don't want to do anything then remove that line and leave the body blank.

```
 private object Session(string p)
 {
    // Put your code 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a usual code injected by visual studio, when you require to implement some specified interface. So visual studio generates required method body with this exception inside.

Possible solutions thow:

1) implement it

2) validate: do you really need to derive from the interface your class derives.

3) comment exception raising and `return null` (unpredicted behavior, based completely on your application structure, good as fast solution, but the worst between all other options)

Answer (score 0):

You can either implement the method

**OR** comment the content and return `null` like:

```
private object Session(string p)
{
   // throw new NotImplementedException();
   return null;
}
```